# How to search XX and if this found then search in the next line for YY?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, scripting

I would like to search XX and if this found then search in the next line for YY.

Only display result when YY is found at the next line after XX.

Could someone help me to script this please?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/XX/!d;n;/YY/p' file
```

will print only the YY lines which are immediately preceded by an XX line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly. It will print out standalone `XX` lines by fall-through. As well as printing out the `XX` lines that are immediately before the desired `YY` lines. No?

Comment: I think you need `-n` and `;p` (at the end) to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -A 1 XX file | grep -v XX | grep YY`